# Connecting to ubuntu runnning rmate via multiple machines on the same network

Tags: networking, ssh, textmate

I've got an ubuntu server with `rmate` installed (that's a [nice little package](http://blog.macromates.com/2011/mate-and-rmate/) that lets you ssh to a server and edit remote files on your [TextMate](https://macromates.com/), locally).

The original setup claims it supports multiple machines accessing the same server, using the same port but **different users**. See the first link above.

For some reason when we ssh to two **different users** but on the same port from the same network, we're crossing paths. That means:

If two users exit - `a@server.com` and `b@server.com`, and `a` ssh-es via port 999 to server.com and `b` ssh-es via port 999 to server.com **from the same network**, if `a` writes `rmate file` on his terminal, `b` gets the file in his text editor **in addition** to `a`.

Hope this make sense - my networking game is not on point.

Comment: Are you using a configuration as explained in the article [mate and rmate](http://blog.macromates.com/2011/mate-and-rmate/), section "Port Forwarding" at the end?

Comment: I am. Something specific there that you think I might be missing?

Comment: Yeah it was the textmate port thing - mussed that! I think I approved the bounty as well, no?

Comment: Works on my mac, but I'll wait for my partners to connect on windows and let you know we're not crossong wires. Thanks for taking the time, tho. ;)

Comment: If you could specify steps for sublime on windows, actually, that would really help my partners.

Comment: [Sublime Text, Putty, and You](https://blog.cs.wmich.edu/sublime-text-putty-and-you/). This example use the default port, so please use a different port from your connection in Mac.

Comment: Will give it a go. Anything that needs changing on the server? Besidea running the different command? Something in the rmate config files?

Comment: You may keep server as is. However, you should read the [blog link](http://blog.macromates.com/2011/mate-and-rmate/) again for how to set ssh & rmate to work without specifying all parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you install and run `rmate text` locally, `text` will show in TextMate. This is because TextMate listens on localhost:52698 and rmate talks to localhost:52698 by default.

If you set TextMate>Preference>Terminal>Port to 52678, connect by `ssh -R 52677:localhost:52678 user@server.com` and run `rmate -p 52677 text` remotely,
rmate will talk to localhost(of server.com):52677 which will then be tunneled to localhost(of your ssh client):52678 and `text` will show in TextMate.

For users from different hosts (eg. [#1](https://github.com/textmate/rmate/issues/15), [#2](https://github.com/randy3k/remote-atom/issues/37)), tunnel source port must be different, eg. `[user1|user2]` may keep TextMate port as is but connect with `[52678|52679]:localhost:52698` and use `rmate -p [52678|52679]` respectively.

For users from the same host, both tunnel source and destination ports must be different among users, eg. `[user1|user2]` set TextMate port to `[52678|52679]`, connect with `[52678|52679]:localhost:[52678|52679]` and use `rmate -p [52678|52679]` respectively.

Comment: This answer is based on testing with **Sublime Text 2** + [rsub](https://github.com/henrikpersson/rsub) on Windows & `rmate-bash` hosted on Ubuntu desktop. Feel free to ask if there is anything unclear, as I afraid my explanation is inadequate.

Comment: Can you clarify the last part? Why is it different?

Comment: To ensure that the ssh tunnel <src ip, src port, dest ip, dest port> is unique. users from different hosts have different "dest ip", so "dest port" can be the same. users from the same host have same "dest ip", so "dest port" should be different.